# How to generate PDF from popup in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs, puppeteer

I know that you can download a PDF with Puppeteer using:

```
await page.pdf({path: 'page.pdf'});
```

But how can I download a PDF from a popup?

Sample code to go to the popup URL:

```
 let popup = pages.pop();
 await popup.waitFor(7500); 
 await page.goto(popup.url());
```

How can I get the PDF and save it to a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`page.pdf()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions) to save the popup (the last element in [`browser.pages()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#browserpages)) as a PDF:

```
const pages = await browser.pages();
const popup = pages[pages.length - 1];

await popup.pdf({
  path: 'popup.pdf'
});
```

Comment: I had to set headless to true in Puppeteer launch, as PDF seems to be not available in non headless mode. But still PDF is not saved.

Comment: I get timeout and nothing happens.

Comment: And when headless is true, popup is not there so pages.length is actually one. Any ideas?